# Is it possible in c# to access class instance having only property value?

Tags: c#, class, reflection

May be it's silly question , but is it possible to realize such scenario?
I have a class , e.g.

```
public class Car
{
public string Make {get;set;}
public string Model {get;set;}
public decimal Price {get;set;}
public User Owner {get;set;}
}
```

where owner is the property setting somewhere else and than i have a function

```
public static class Operations
    {
public static void CalculateTaxes(decimal price)
       {
           ....some code goes here and I want using reflection to access Owner,supposing that i will always pass price of a car
       }
    }
```

that function will be called like this

```
var car =new Car(){Price=25000,Make="BMW",Model="X6",Owner=new User(){"Sam Johnson"}};
Operations.CalculateTaxes(car.Price);
```

This is just a fake code, in real app I don't want to pass the whole instance , but want to get hold of the car owner.Is it a real goal ?

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the instance?

Comment: You cannot do that as you are just passing the price of the car.

Comment: that's not possible. you are copying the `decimal` value when passing to `CalculatePrice`

Comment: No, you can't do that with reflection, but also doing so would be quite confusing. You are obviously going to predicate some logic on the owner, but it is not obvious to the caller that the owner would in any way be relevant if all that is asked for is the price.

Comment: But i can do a lot of things within that function, e.g. calling nameof(price). the reason why I don't want to pass object , is that function is used to operate with values ,not with whole object

Comment: So pass two parameters, the price and the owner, like `CalculateTaxes(decimal price, Owner owner)`.

Comment: @mikez No for sure I will call that function only with Car properties,that is the issue.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yea, that is evidently, but not very elegant solution, there will a lot of overriden functions and  I want to make them compact

Comment: @alekoo73 If it's meant to operate with values, it should only operate with those values. If there are other types that you want to operate on, you should declare an interface that presents the basic information necessary and have the objects you intend to operate on implement that interface.

Comment: "but not very elegant solution"; well, the most elegant solution would be to pass the entire object, but for some reason you've ruled that out. Plus, if you're using reflection, elegance has long since left the building :).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is simple and short: No.
This is not possible, under any circumstance- because of how C# is designed. Thank Mads for that.

Imagine the security implications of passing an integer to a compromised 3rd party library- and accidentally leaking user credentials by doing so.

The real issue here is a design issue.
Your code is not designed to suit the needs of your application.
Rethink your design.

Also note that while reflection has many use cases and enables a lot of things,
in such simple cases- it is usually overkill.
Use reflection for meta programming - not for business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can that not be done with `decimal` which is a value type. Even a reference type such as a class won't work because (AFAIK) classes do not keep track of all of the objects that point to them (The same class instance can be a property of multiple owners).

Fortunately there's a simple solution - pass the car instance itself, and extract the price from it.

```
public static void CalculateTaxes(Car car)
{
    decimal price = car.Price;
    ...
}
```

If you need to call this method with types other than `Car`, you can create an appropriate interface and have `Car` implement it. Such as an interface with an `Owner` property. But since you're trying to get more properties of the car, I'm assuming this is going to be used only for type `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of that solution ,but it's now what I want,as there will be a lot of properties of different type and each of them should be process in a different function and I want to pass them using dot notation ,not like `CalculateTax(car,"Price")`

I think , that the best solution will be to use local functions, which will have access to the whole object like

```
public static class Operations
    {
    public static void Operate(Car car)
       {
           calculateTaxes(car.Price);
         void calculateTaxes(decimal price)
         { 
          car.Owner is accessible here 
          }

         void rateMake(string make)
         { 
          so on and so on
          }


       }

    }
```